# kconfig.cmake Error: command failed with return code: 1

Tags: cmake

I am trying to setup CMake to work with zephyr, the toolchain is installed. When I try to configure, I get this error, and I do not understand how to fix it.

I am working with a BT510 Sensor. I am trying to get its readings and send it by bluetooth to another carrier.

If my approach is valid, how can I fix this error?
If not, what are my alternatives to work with BT510?

Here is the whole CMake window with the error:

```
Loading Zephyr default modules (Zephyr base (cached)).
Application: C:/Users/omars/OneDrive/Desktop/BT
Cache files will be written to: C:/Users/omars/zephyrproject/zephyr/.cache
Zephyr version: 3.0.99 (C:/Users/omars/zephyrproject/zephyr)
Found west (found suitable version "0.12.0", minimum required is "0.7.1")
Board: bt510
Found toolchain: gnuarmemb (C:/Program Files (x86)/gnu_arm_embedded)
Found BOARD.dts: C:/Users/omars/zephyrproject/zephyr/boards/arm/bt510/bt510.dts
Generated zephyr.dts: C:/Users/omars/OneDrive/Desktop/BT/build/zephyr/zephyr.dts
Generated devicetree_unfixed.h: C:/Users/omars/OneDrive/Desktop/BT/build/zephyr/include/generated/devicetree_unfixed.h
Generated device_extern.h: C:/Users/omars/OneDrive/Desktop/BT/build/zephyr/include/generated/device_extern.h
Including generated dts.cmake file: C:/Users/omars/OneDrive/Desktop/BT/build/zephyr/dts.cmake
Parsing C:/Users/omars/OneDrive/Desktop/BT/Kconfig
Loaded configuration 'C:/Users/omars/zephyrproject/zephyr/boards/arm/bt510/bt510_defconfig'
Merged configuration 'C:/Users/omars/OneDrive/Desktop/BT/prj.conf'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\omars\zephyrproject\zephyr\scripts\kconfig\kconfig.py", line 278, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\omars\zephyrproject\zephyr\scripts\kconfig\kconfig.py", line 65, in main
    if kconf.syms['WARN_EXPERIMENTAL'].tri_value == 1:
KeyError: 'WARN_EXPERIMENTAL'

CMake Error at C:/Users/omars/zephyrproject/zephyr/cmake/modules/kconfig.cmake:289 (message):
  command failed with return code: 1

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/omars/zephyrproject/zephyr/cmake/modules/zephyr_default.cmake:121 (include)
  C:/Users/omars/zephyrproject/zephyr/share/zephyr-package/cmake/ZephyrConfig.cmake:45 (include)
  C:/Users/omars/zephyrproject/zephyr/share/zephyr-package/cmake/ZephyrConfig.cmake:75 (include_boilerplate)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you just added `C:/Users/omars/OneDrive/Desktop/BT/Kconfig` you may be missing `source "${ZEPHYR_BASE}/Kconfig.zephyr"`

`WARN_EXPERIMENTAL` (and `EXPERIMENTAL`) is a weird conf as it is hard coded in kconfig.py to be interpreted. the conf needs to exists for kconfig.py to run.

I recon your last change in `C:/Users/omars/OneDrive/Desktop/BT/Kconfig` excluded the definition of the configuration from `C:/Users/omars/zephyrproject/zephyr/Kconfig.zephyr` somehow.

Precedance in finding the root Kconfig goes as follow (kconfig.cmake). Priority is `KCONFIG_ROOT` cmake env var,otherwise a `Kconfig` file in app directory, finally the zephyr top level Kconfig.

```
if(KCONFIG_ROOT)
  zephyr_file(APPLICATION_ROOT KCONFIG_ROOT)
  # KCONFIG_ROOT has either been specified as a CMake variable or is
  # already in the CMakeCache.txt. This has precedence.
elseif(EXISTS   ${APPLICATION_SOURCE_DIR}/Kconfig)
  set(KCONFIG_ROOT ${APPLICATION_SOURCE_DIR}/Kconfig)
else()
  set(KCONFIG_ROOT ${ZEPHYR_BASE}/Kconfig)
endif()
```